# How to access to this xml field?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

When i var_dump this:

```
while($row = $updDate->fetch()){//GET FEEDS WHICH UPDATED DATE IS NOT IN DB
        var_dump($this->soccer->GetAllOddsByFixtureMatchId(
        array("fixtureMatch_Id"=>$row['FixtureMatch_Id'])));
        echo $row['FixtureMatch_Id'];}
```

It returns me this feed.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[11]
public 'OddsList' => 
object(SimpleXMLElement)[12]
  public 'Odds' => 
    array (size=37)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[13]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[14]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[15]
          ...
      3 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[16]
          ...
      4 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[17]
          ...
      5 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[18]
          ...
      6 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[19]
          ...
object(SimpleXMLElement)[11]
public 'OddsList' => 
object(SimpleXMLElement)[12]
  public 'Odds' => 
    array (size=37)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[49]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[48]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[47]
          ...
      3 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[46]
          ...
      4 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[45]
          ...
      5 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[44]
          ...
      6 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[43]
          ...
object(SimpleXMLElement)[11]
public 'OddsList' => 
object(SimpleXMLElement)[12]
  public 'Odds' => 
    array (size=37)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[13]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[14]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[15]
          ...
      3 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[16]
          ...
      4 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[17]
          ...
      5 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[18]
          ...
      6 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[19]
          ...
```

I want to access Odds object and get some columns from and compare it from columns in my database...

It works good when i use:

> ->OddsList->Odds

, but i need xpath for some conditions... So i tried to add this `->xpath('/OddsList/Odds'))`, but it returns me null...

Comment: Does the XML has *default namespace*, something like `xmlns="foo.bar"`?

Comment: yes i think for input:

<GetOddsByFixtureMatchId xmlns="http://xmlsoccer.com/">
      <ApiKey>string</ApiKey>
      <fixtureMatch_Id>string</fixtureMatch_Id>
    </GetOddsByFixtureMatchId>

Comment: first look at the structure of the XML, and add it to your question:  `echo $xml->asXML();` IMO much cleaner than the `var_dump`. Then compose the xpath from there.

Comment: asXML returns me all data without xml tags, i am not sure that i understand you. I just want to compare uploadates and add differents to my database without searching full feed, just check if diff exists if does get it, else continue search...

Comment: either look at the source-code of what you get in the browser, or do `echo htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath works against XML, so it's hard to tell the exact problem and solution without being able to see the XML. I would guess the problem was due to existence of *default namespace*. Consider the following sample XML :

```
<OddsList xmlns="xmlsoccer.com/">
    <Odd>1</Odd> 
    <Odd>2</Odd> 
</OddsList>
```

There is a default namespace pointing to address `"xmlsoccer.com"` in above XML sample. Note that **descendant elements inherit ancestor *default namespace* implicitly, unless otherwise specified** (using explicit namespace prefix, or having local default namespace pointing to different URI). In this case, you need to **register mapping of prefix to namespace URI, and use the registered prefix properly in the XPath**. For example :

```
$string = <<<XML
<OddsList xmlns="xmlsoccer.com/">
    <Odd>1</Odd> 
    <Odd>2</Odd> 
</OddsList>
XML;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("d","xmlsoccer.com/");
foreach($xml->xpath("/d:OddsList/d:Odd") as $node)
{
    echo $node ."<br>";
}
```

**<kbd>[`Demo`](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/mmdXEG)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
1
2
```

Comment: I found solution, but thanks, this helps me in another situation.

Comment: If the answer does not answer the actual question, please do not accept it. Instead add your answer below in your own words, not just a comment that you found a solution your own.